# Passing a value to anonymous function as a function argument

Tags: javascript, function, scope

y1 and year1 are undefined inside the anonymous function, which is a parameter to circle.attr(). However, 'year1' does have the right value before the code enters circle.attr().  Could someone explain why this is?
**I did get the function to work by replacing the 2nd parameter with "xYear(y)"

```
function circleLocation(y) {
  year1 = y
  console.log(year1)
  circle.attr('cx', function(year1) {
    y1 = year1;
    console.log(y1)
    console.log(year1)
    return xYear(y);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining `year1`. Arguments of a function are like variables inside their scope. So this:

```
function (year1) {
    // ...
```

Is more or less the same as: (has the same effect but it's not the same thing)

```
function() {
    var year1;
    // ...
```

The `year1` variable is shadowing the other `year1` (the one you want). Try this:

```
circle.attr('cx', function() { // without the argument year1
    y1 = year1;
    console.log(y1)
    console.log(year1)
    return xYear(y);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, it looks like you're introducing global variables so I'd suggest using `var` to prevent this from happening.

```
var year1 = y;
```

Next, it's hard to understand but I think you're confused about why `year1` has a value before executing your anonymous function and why it's `undefined` inside of the anonymous function.

The problem here is that you're *shadowing* the other variable. Your anonymous function takes a parameter named `year1`

```
circle.attr('cx', function(year1) {
  ...
```

That means you have declared a variable named `year1` inside of that functions scope. Whenever you declare a variable inside of a scope, that declaration will shadow the previous declaration. That means, it's a whole new variable and doesn't correlate with the previous one.

```js
var x = 2;

function useGlobal() {
  // No x is declared here so it grabs the next available x value
  // which is the global one
  console.log(x);
}

function hideX(x) {
  // Here we've said that the function takes a parameter named x
  // This means we can no longer access the outer variable named x
  console.log(x); // undefined
}

function declareX() {
  // Same thing as before, we've declared a new x so the old
  // one is shadowed
  var x = 500;
  console.log(x);
}

useGlobal();
hideX();
declareX();

// Notice how declareX didn't change the original x
useGlobal();
```

Answer (score 0):

you not have introduced a parameters in function `circleLocation(args)`

```js
function circleLocation(y) {
  year1 = y
  console.log(year1)
  attr('cx', function(year1) {
    y1 = year1;
    console.log(y1)
    console.log(year1)
    return xYear(y);
  })
}


function attr(n,fun){
}
circleLocation(4);
```